# How to average the time data type?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I have a dataset that I would like to do some analysis on. The dataset gave response times in the time datatype for different time periods, and I have been struggling to find a way to get an average time for all the values using SQL. Here is the format that they are in.

```
hh:mm:ss

00:07:11
00:07:26 
00:07:58 
00:10:19
```

Etc. Across different rows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Convert everything to seconds, i.e. multiply the hh part with 3600, mm part with 60 and keep seconds part as is. Find the sum of all of these, calculate average on that.  Then convert the result back to hours , minutes and seconds.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/73167606/5221944

Answer (score 0):

Using [time functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions) in Bigquery you can get the average:

```sql
WITH `sample_db` AS (
  SELECT TIME '00:07:11' time UNION ALL
  SELECT '00:07:26' UNION ALL    
  SELECT '00:07:58' UNION ALL    
  SELECT '00:10:19' 
)

SELECT 
  TIME_ADD(TIME '00:00:00', INTERVAL CAST(AVG(TIME_DIFF(time, TIME '00:00:00', SECOND)) AS INT64) SECOND) average_time
FROM `sample_db`;
```

Output:

[image]